# Unable to use PushToTalkButton of Speechly in react app

Tags: reactjs, speech-recognition

I am working with **Speechly API** in my react application. In that, I imported **PushToTalkButton** and **PushToTalkButtonContainer** from **@speechly/react-ui** and I have also configured from Speechly Playground it's working fine in Playground. Then I click on the button(PushToTalkButton) in react application it is not capturing my voice and not using the microphone. I tried to find out the problem with **ErrorPanel** but nothing is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try upgrading to version 1.2.4 by issuing `npm install @speechly/react-ui@latest`

Earlier versions were inadvertently coupled with a certain version of react-client package and might cause a problem you described.